# VS2013 MVC Controller dialog loses model classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Firstly, I'm new to ASP.Net and MVC, so still finding my feet. I seem to have a problem whereby when I close and re-open my project, the list of 'Model Class' shown in the 'Add Controller' dialog comes up blank and no matter what I do I cannot get it to show anything and yes I have tried rebuilding and searching the net for a solution.

I've broken my process down into some real simple steps that reproduce the problem every time...

1) Create new ASP.Net MVC5 project

2) Add a model class

3) Create a db context class within a DAL folder

4) Save and build

5) Right-click to add a controller, the dialog shows the list of model classes in the drop down. Click cancel.

6) Close the project and then re-open the project, you don’t need to close VS.

7) Rebuild the project

8) Right-click to add a controller, the dialog now shows a blank list of model classes in the drop down. Arghh!

I can only assume I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Do you mean the list of model classes when creating the view?

Comment: Thats not quite what I was adding, but yes, if I also try to add a view and pick a template that accepts a model class the model class drop down is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Bingo! Just two steps

1)[Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41204) your Visual studio 2013 to new update release.

2) unload your project from solution explorer then Reload it again.